# Change html slider step exponentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am trying to change the slider step by the power of `10` on each slide but it's not working correctly. I am unsure if I should use `stepUp()` or change the value of value of step directly.

This is how I increment by the power of `10`:

```
var increment = (function(n) {
  return function() {
    n = n + 2;
    var x = Math.pow(10, n);
    console.log(x +" " + "Math.Pow thingy");
    return x;
  }
```

Here is how I try to pass it as an argument:

```
document.getElementById("something").stepUp(increment);
```

In case anyone is wondering, here is the [stepUp()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_range_stepup.asp) that I am using.

Also, here is a fiddle of my slider: [Slider Fiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/ZombieChowder/5fpg8p75/8/)

> I want my slider to step to change to `10`,`100`,`1000`,`10000` on each slide.

Comment: Your code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need the closure or to return a function. You just need to call `increment` within the `oninput` handler. That said it's not clear what you're trying to do. Your slider is a few hundred pixels wide. Therefore, assuming 500px, the result when slid to the right would be `9.765625e+26`... Are you *sure* that's what you want to do?

Comment: my idea is just to have a minimum of `100` and a maximum of `1 000 000 000` so increasing the slider step by the power of `10` should't be an issue. 

It's just that I cannot find sufficient enough documentation to see how to solve this.

Comment: According to the linked page `.stepUp()` accepts Number, not Function.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you can't really do it your way, you'll need to do some kind of calculation yourself. Step only works for constant numbers

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input")
var output = document.getElementById("output")

function getValue() {
  let power = input.value
  let result = Math.pow(10, +power)
  output.value = result
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" oninput="getValue()" />

<input type="text" id="output" value="10"/>
```

Comment: when I call it dynamically `'<input id="input" type="range" name="insulationResistance" min="1" max="10" value="'+ data.insulationResistance + '"oninput="' + getValue() + '">'` I get a : `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` but it works in the code snippet. Thanks for that

Comment: instead of using `"` and `'`' use template literals instead `\``, makes it much easier if you're writing it in string format.

Answer (score 1):

The natural behaviour of `<input type="range" />` is linear, so you have to engineer the required mapping of natural values to required values.

What you are looking for is  slider with a socalled *log-linear* action such that the slider is set up to yield the logarithm of the values you ultimately want;

```
<input id="something" name="something" type="range" min="2" max="5" value="3" step="1" class="form-control slider" />
```

Here, the critical settings are

- **min="2"** - log-base10(100) == 2
- **max="5"** - log-base10(100000) == 5
- **value="3"** - log-base10(1000) == 3

Then to get back to the values you actually want, you have to do an anti-logarithm, or `Math.pow(10, x)`.

```
var slider = document.getElementById('something');
var output = document.getElementById('demo');
slider.onchange = function() {
    output.innerHTML = Math.pow(10, this.value);
}
slider.onchange(); // set output for the initial value
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/36vek0ny/)**

EDIT:

The behaviour of an `<input type="range" />` slider element is inescapably linear. At its current state of development, HTML offers nothing else.

In order to submit the value you actually want, you can use your slider field as the UI for an underlying hidden field, the value of which is maintained to hold a transform of the linear element's value. Providing you can write code to perform the transformation, you are in business. In this case, it's simple - antilogarithm.

So your HTML might be something like this :

```
<input id="something-ui" type="range" min="2" max="5" value="3" step="1" class="form-control slider" />
<input id="something-hidden" name="something" type="hidden" />
```

And the corresponding javascript :

```
var slider = document.getElementById('something-ui');
var hidden = document.getElementById('something-hidden');
var output = document.getElementById('demo');
slider.oninput = function() { // or onChange
    output.innerHTML = hidden.value = Math.pow(10, this.value); // antilogarithm
}
slider.oninput(); // set hidden value and output for the initial value
```

So now, the UI control still behaves linearly but is given (by `demo`) the appearance, and a submit behaviour (by `something-hidden`), of being exponential.

Comment: yeah but the value that you pass is between **2** and **5**. The reason for increase by power of 10 is that I work with values between 1 and 10000000.

Comment: You mean on form submission?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but it keeps returning `slider.onchange()` is not a function. Another thing is that you've wrote `slider.onInput` and it should be `slider.oninput`.

Comment: Yes, try `slider.oninput = ... ` and `slider.oninput()`

Comment: yeah I fixed those things. However, I still keep passing values such as **2** or **5** instead of the ones I want. I think, I'll just set a bounty on the question.

Comment: I can't see how that can be. The `name="something"` field can only ever be empty or have a value of 100, 1000, 10000, 10000; never 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: it's because you have `min` and `max` in the slider, operating as upper and lower boundary. When you set the values from 100 to 100000, you still use those single digits values. Meaning that even if you show **1000** on the html page, the value that you pass to the back end (nodejs in this case) is between the set `min` and `max` parameters in the slider html. Does that make sense ?

Comment: That would make sense if we were talking about the the element `id="something-ui"` but not the element `name="something"`. Form elements without a name should not be submitted, so there should be no chance of confusion at the server. Are you sure your HTML is exactly as I typed it?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do this

```js
// Get DOM refs for the required elements
var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
var res = document.getElementById('res');
var inc = document.getElementById('inc');

// Initialize Div to show starting value
res.innerHTML = slider.value;

// Register on change handler to update div value if slider is changed
slider.onchange = function(){
  res.innerHTML = this.value;
}

// Register a click handler inside a closure to increment exponentially
inc.onclick = (function(){
    // Initial increment value
    var n = 1;
    // Return a click handler function which has access to the variable n because of the closure
    return function(){
      // Button is clicked, increment by n
      slider.stepUp(n);
      // Update div value for display
      res.innerHTML = slider.value;
      // Multilply n by 10 so the next time the increment is 10x
      n *= 10;
    }
})()
```

```html
<input type="range" id="myRange" value="1000" min="1" max="1000">
<div id="res"></div>

<button id="inc">Increment</button>
```